# Write comment in config files with python

Tags: python, comments, configparser

I need to write some comment in a configuration file generated at *runtime* via `ConfigParser` library in Python.

I want to write a full descriptive comment like:

```
########################
# FOOBAR section 
# do something 
########################
[foobar]
bar = 1
foo = hallo
```

The code should look like:

Where I insert comment and configurations options in the same moment.

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

config.insert_comment("##########################") # This function is purely hypothetical 
config.insert_comment("# FOOBAR section ")
....

config.add_section('foobar')
config.set('foobar', 'bar', '1')
config.set('foobar', 'foo', 'hallo')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the docs:

Lines beginning with '#' or ';' are ignored and may be used to provide comments.

Configuration files may include comments, prefixed by specific characters (# and ;). Comments may appear on their own in an otherwise empty line, or may be entered in lines holding values or section names. In the latter case, they need to be preceded by a whitespace character to be recognized as a comment. (For backwards compatibility, only ; starts an inline comment, while # does not.)

Examples:

```
conf.set('default_settings', '; comment here', '')
```

or

```
[default_settings]
    ; comment here = 
    test = 1

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
print config.items('default_settings')

>>>
[('test','1')] # as you see comment is not parsed
```

Comment: Ok I've read the documentation. But I really need to add a comment line runtime, that's useful for editing by hand the config file.

Comment: See the examples, Is that what you mean?

Comment: Hi Root I have this as my properties and it keeps returning True

`# Via .py directory
data.extension=False

# Via API
# data.extension=True
`

Comment: You have to use `getboolean('property')` to translate the string `True/False` into a boolean value.